# How to include javaspark libraries in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-studio, import

i'm developing an Android app in Android Studio and I need the [javaspark](http://sparkjava.com/) features to use my app remotely.All the tutorials that I found are good for Eclipse or Maven projects(i'm not familiar with these ones).Is there something that i'm missing?